# Spring issue with profile

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the variables uploaded directly based on environment in which the code is running. I wrote some  code and ran into issues. Can you please point me what i am doing wrong.

WebAppInitializer.java

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
// Create the 'root' Spring application context
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
root.scan("com.configs");
root.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("dev");
root.refresh();


// Manages the lifecycle of the root application context
sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

// Handles requests into the application
ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = sc.addServlet("appServlet",
                               new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
Set<String> mappingConflicts = appServlet.addMapping("/");

if (!mappingConflicts.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "'appServlet' could not be mapped to '/' due "
                    + "to an existing mapping. This is a known issue under Tomcat versions "
                    + "<= 7.0.14; see https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51278");
}

}
```

}

DynamicConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
@PropertySource("classpath:/devel.properties")

public class DynamicConfig {

@Autowired 
Environment env;

@Bean
public TestClass testClass(){
    TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
    testClass.setEnvironment(env.getProperty("environment"));
    return testClass;       
}
```

}

TestClass is simple class with one instance variable which will come from config based on environment.

TestCase:
     package com.tester;

```
 import org.junit.Test;
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

 import com.configs.DynamicConfig;
  import com.configs.EnvironmentDetector;
 import com.tester.TestClass;

 public class TestClassTest {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DynamicConfig.class);

 @Test
public void test(){
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DynamicConfig.class);
   context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("dev");
     context.scan("com.configs");
    TestClass test = context.getBean(TestClass.class);
    System.out.println(test.getEnvironment());
}
```

}

Now I am getting below error

```
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.282 sec <<< FAILURE!
  test(com.tester.TestClassTest)  Time elapsed: 0.279 sec  <<< ERROR!
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.tester.TestClass] is defined: expected single bean but found 0: 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:280)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106)
at com.tester.TestClassTest.test(TestClassTest.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:87)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

When i remove the line **@profile("dev")** from the DynamicConfig.java code is running fine. But i want that. I want to create similar classes for prod.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your test class to activate the profile.  Currently you are activating it by adding the property in the WebApplicationInitializer which is not run in the context of your test.

One way to activate it would be doing the following, however it is not the only way:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ActiveProfiles({"dev"})
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = {DynamicConfig.class})
 public class TestClassTest {

 @Autowired
 TestClass testClass;

 @Test
 public void test(){
      System.out.println(testClass.getEnvironment());
 }
```

Comment: Hi... your approach worked thanks a lot. Can you correct me other approach... I updated the testcase... The updated testCase is not working even after activating profile. I am trying to follow this link: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/